# Dual Booting Kali Linux with Windows 7. Atheros Killer E2200 not found + 2 different HDD

Tags: windows-7, drivers, grub, debian-wheezy, multi-boot

I'm having trouble installing Kali on a MSI GE70 2OE with a SSD HD and a standard SATA HD.

I've installed W7 on the SSD, and then partitioned my SATA in two parts: One 800Gb for W7 and another 200Gb of empty space to install Kali. There's as well 2Gb occupied by a FreeDos installation on my SATA that I've left just in case.

First problem: When installing Kali my Atheros Killer 2200 netword card is not recognized. I've found possible solutions to this problem AFTER the installation, but so far I don't have access to a console (nor I can use a package administrator). I've to pass this point without installing drivers for my ethernet card and with no access to internet.

Second problem: I can't install a package administrator. No internet -> No package administrator. I've to skip this point as well. Is this really troublesome?

Third and final problem: I can't install GRUB. When starting the GRUB installation the only SO that finds is FreeDos, that is in my SATA along with Kali. I've tried all possibilities to install GRUB but none works: /dev/sda -> MBR for SATA disk (I think). It doesn't work /dev/sda5 - Partition for Kali, 200 Gb. It doesn't work /dev/sda6 -> SWAP space, 10Gb. Doesn't work /dev/sdb -> W7 on my SSD, 128Gb. Doesn't work.

I think I didn't try sda2 where my FreeDos is, but I guess it wouldn't work anyway.

I would like to know if I can fix the network card problem during installation, and specially I would like to know how to install GRUB, as this is the point where I'm stack.

Thanks in advance! I'm almost a noob on linux. Don't hesitate to ask me for more details.

Comment: Kali does not activate network connections at boot by design. You have to do it manually. I strongly suggest you first cut your teeth on a more friendly Linux distro (Ubuntu? Mint?), and after some time you move on to Kali. Otherwise Kali will make your life as miserable as it is right now.

Comment: If I've to choose between doing it now ot later I prefer now. This shouldn't be so complicated I think.